# How do I programmatically activate pages to only certain replication agents in AEM?

Tags: workflow, aem

How do I programmatically activate pages to only certain replication agents in AEM using Replication API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AEM provides `ReplicationOptions` API. This can help [selecting the replication agent](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5ReplicateToSpecificAgents.html) using `public void setFilter(AgentFilter filter)`.

Agent can be named as per requirement, the API can match exact Agent name in `public void setFilter(AgentFilter filter)` or  regex can be used to match required agents.

Also refer [another answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315967/cq-aem-staging-concept-with-workflows/35424165#35424165)

Comment: can you post sample code ? I am getting NPE on replicate method.


ReplicationOptions opts = new ReplicationOptions();
AgentIdFilter repAgentFilter = new AgentIdFilter("publish0");
opts.setFilter(repAgentFilter);
replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, pagePath, opts);

Comment: Sample code is given in the link given in answer. Can you add the error trace to question? Have you injected the replicator reference?

Comment: thanks a lot.. its worked.